# Trouble with getting national characters in QFileDialog working

Tags: c++, qt, encoding, internationalization, qfiledialog

I'm trying to take start using Qt and decided to poke around [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-textedit-example.html) text editor first.

Everything goes fine except some strange behaviour of QFileDialog - I can not manage it to deal with national charset.

Here is what I see when running compiled binary and trying to open file:

[image: Problem dialog]

I've tried to search the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html) and [qt wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Strings_and_encodings_in_Qt) in order to get some clues, but there is nothing about i18n that could be readable for newbie like me.

So here is the problem code:

```
void TextEdit::fileOpen()
{
    QString fn = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File..."),
                                              QString(), tr("HTML-Files (*.htm *.html);;All Files (*)"));
    if (!fn.isEmpty())
        load(fn);
}
```

I guess I should attach `::fromUtf8()` here somehow, but have no understanding of how this should be done.

**UPD**

Tried to change default locale just [as advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313896/changing-locale-in-qt):

```
QLocale curLocale(QLocale("ru_RU"));
QLocale::setDefault(curLocale);
```

Also tried this variant:

```
QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(QLocale::Russian, QLocale::RussianFederation));
```

This did not help, problem persists.

Comment: I don't think `::fromUtf8()` is involved here:) Qt should be fully Unicode aware, could it be that there is an issue with the locale?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis updated