# Change Qt language used by Qt Widgets

Tags: c++, qt, multilingual, qmessagebox

i'm currently using several times `QMessageBox`, but whenever i do

```
msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
```

this shows 2 buttons with realtive `No` and `Yes` labels, however my application is based on another language, and so I was wondering if there were some `QLocal / QApplication` (maybe) settings to change in order to translate those labels to my desiderd language.

I've tried

```
QLocale ql(QLocale::Language,QLocale::Country);
msgBox.setLocale(ql);
```

But it doesn't seems to work, and neither

```
QLocale::setDefault(QLocale(QLocale::Language,QLocale::Country));
```

has worked for me

Comment: Did you verify whether your language has a translation for Yes and No, or at all?

Comment: @Botje yep, but i've founded https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313896/changing-locale-in-qt that has worked in the end